# why julia is generating a complex conjugate upon entering a complex number?

Tags: julia

While attempting to enter any complex number in julia console e.g. 2+3im and then pressing the enter key, the output is same as the input, i.e. 2 + 3im. But upon entering the input is in rational form i.e. 1//2+1//5im, and upon pressing the enter key julia outputs 1//2 - 1//5*im.
kindly help
i am on ubuntu 18.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This happens because juxtaposition binds tighter than (almost?) all operators, so your input is parsed as

```
julia> 1//2 + 1//(5im)
1//2 - 1//5*im
```

instead of the

```
julia> 1//2 + (1//5)im
1//2 + 1//5*im
```

you wanted. That gives the opposite sign from what you expected, because of course `im^(-1) == -im`.

Answer (score 5):

You need something to indicate that it is the rational number `1//5` which is imaginary and not just the `5`.

```
julia> 1//2 + (1//5)im
1//2 + 1//5*im

julia> 1//2 + 1//5*im
1//2 + 1//5*im
```

whereas

```
julia> 1//2 + 1//(5*im)
1//2 - 1//5*im
```